# Flask spotipy cache issue

Tags: python, flask, spotipy

I am trying to build a small Flask app hosted on PythonAnywhere for displaying playlists. I don't need the users to login to do this and I am using the SpotifyClientCredentials to hook up to the API.

The app works fine... until a second user tries it. Then there is a cache error which looks like this in the error log:

```
2022-03-09 22:36:43,627: Couldn't read cache at: .cache
2022-03-09 22:36:43,692: Couldn't write token to cache at: .cache
```

And the current user will see results from the previous one as a result.

The app works fine locally, but there are issues when more than one user tries to use it. I really don't need any data store from one session to the other.

I am really new at this and the answer could be very obvious, but I just can't seem to figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are severe space restrictions on PythonAnywhere free. Could be that.

Answer (score 0):

From the responses in [this issue](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/579), that appears to be just a warning.